# Eliminating duplicates from a list while summing over a non-duplicated variable

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, text

I'm have a text file of a telescope with three columns, RA, DEC and TIME. RA and DEC are sky coordinates, while TIME is the time of observation at that coordinates. While RA and DEC are repeated in many entries, the time in each entry is not, i.e., one can point to (RA,DEC)=(120,30) first 2 hours, then 4 more, and finally 1 more. The idea is to use python to write another text file in which each pair of coordinates only appears once, with the time being the sum of all times in that coordinates. Of course, some coordinates are only observed once, so they have no repetition.

I made some attempts and at the moment I managed to write the same input file but the first entry of each coordinate is always the good result. The problem is that if a pair of coordinates is repeated, say, 5 times, the text file will write that coordinates 5 times, being the time in the first one the sum and the rest I don't know, but they shouldn't be there

```
import numpy as np

file_all=open('input_file.txt',"r")
data_all   = np.loadtxt(input_file,unpack=True)
time_all = data_all[0]
ra_all   = data_all[1]
dec_all  = data_all[2]

file_new=open('output_file.txt',"w")
file_new.write('#Time   RA           Dec\n')

time_new = np.zeros(len(ra_all))
ra_new = np.zeros(len(ra_all))
dec_new = np.zeros(len(ra_all))

for i in range(len(ra_all)):
    time_new[i]=time_all[i]
    for k in range(len(ra_all)):
        if ((ra_all[i]==ra_all[k]) and i!=k):
            cont = 0
            if i<=k:
                time_new[i]=time_new[i]+time_all[k]
                ra_new[i] = ra_all[i]
                dec_new[i] = dec_all[i]
        elif ((ra_all[i]!=ra_all[k]) and i!=k):
            time_new[i]=time_all[i]
            ra_new[i] = ra_all[i]
            dec_new[i] = dec_all[i]
    if ra_new[i]!=0:
        t = '%.3f   %.5f    %.5f\n' % (time_new[i], ra_new[i], dec_new[i])
        file_new.write(t)
file_new.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary with (RA, DEC) tuple as its keys to achieve this.

```
my_dict = dict()
for i in range(len(data_all)):
    key = (ra_all[i], dec_all[i])
    # get() would return the value of the key if it exists, and 0 otherwise
    value = my_dict.get(key, 0)
    value += time_all[i]
    my_dict[key] = value

for (ra, dec), time in my_dict.items():
    t = '%.3f   %.5f    %.5f\n' % (time, ra, dec)
    file_new.write(t)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I had to replace
`for i in range(len(data_all)):`

by 

`for i in range(len(ra_all)):`

As data_all has len=3